# disable photos & photoset permalinks tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm trying to make all picture posts on my homepage not clickable, so they can't link to the permalinks. (I just want them to stay as miniatures with the hover cycle effect already provided by the theme)

I've tried removing `{LinkOpenTag}` and `{LinkCloseTag}` from:

```
{block:Photo}
<div class="wide-sizer">
    <div class="image">
        {LinkOpenTag}
            <img src="{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}{PhotoURL-500}{/block:IndexPage}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"
                data-high-res="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"
                data-width="{PhotoWidth-HighRes}"
                data-height="{PhotoHeight-HighRes}"
            />
        {LinkCloseTag}
    </div>
```

But photos and photosets are still clickable.

This is my page: http://woodstudiofr.tumblr.com
I'm using the "Spectator Theme".

**UPDATE:** ok so i tried removing as `data-permalink={Permalink}`as **lharby** suggested, but now all the links redirect to  **/undefined**.

Any ideas? 
thanks again for your time !

Comment: You could do it by finding `data-permalink` in your theme and removing it. Not tested but I am fairly certain that is what is being used to trigger the link. There will be some js associated with this, so removing it could cause an error, but it would be a good start.

Comment: It's wrapping the elements that you have in your question. The code should be `data-permalink={Permalink}` try removing any instance of that from the theme.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i did that. Please check my update.

Comment: ok, I think I have an answer I will add it below with some instructions. Please reply back if you cannot get it to work, and also vote if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the `data-permalink` attribute has been removed, but there is still some custom javascript which is casing the url to be returned undefined.

Go to the bottom of your template, before the closing `<body>` tag and add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.post').unbind('click').click(function(){});
   });
</script>
```

(Basically instead of binding the post to a click function which is in the custom javascript we are now attempting to unbind it on click).

I tested it in the browser and it looks to be working (although a couple of other methods I thought would work didn't).

**EDIT**

In order to change the cursor on the post element. Remove the `clickable` class from the .post div from the template (if you can, if it is hard coded in).

Alternatively inside the style tags at the bottom, add the following css:

```
.post-grid .post.photo.clickable a,
.post.clickable {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: beauiful, it works perfectly! just a last minor fix: Is it possible that the mouse pointer stays in a normal state, not the "link hand" state? thanks again !

Comment: Yes there are a few ways to do this. I will update my answer.

Comment: Perfect ! The css to the style tags worked like a charm. Thanks again !